# Image scaling works locally but not when ran from server

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to scale images when loaded into the browser.  Here is my code that I am working with -

```
function importImage(e) {
    var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var reader = new FileReader;

    reader.onload = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var img = new Image;
        img.src = event.target.result;

        img.onload = function() {

        width = img.width;
        height = img.height;        
        var scaleX, scaleY, scale;
        var scaledWidth, scaledHeight;
        scaleX = width / canvas.width;
        scaleY = height / canvas.height;
        scale = scaleX > scaleY ? scaleX : scaleY;
        scaledWidth = width / scale;
        scaledHeight = height / scale;
        ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(img, (canvas.width - scaledWidth) / 2, (canvas.height - scaledHeight) / 2, scaledWidth, scaledHeight);       
        }
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

It seems to works ok when used from a local machine but when it is ran from the server the scaling doesn't work.  I assume it is to do with how I am referring to the actual image but I am unsure.

Comment: Have you checked the JavaScript Console in your browser's developer tools (press F12 from your browser) to see if any errors are being generated on the server? It could be a script reference issue...

Comment: There are no server errors in the browser logs.  dystroy, I'm trying to do an html5 webpage where once the page loads you can send an image to the broswer and have it display in the correct ratio.

Comment: Are you getting any errors you could share?

Comment: Apologies, I got it fixed. Thanks for replying.

It was a conflict between my HTML/CSS, the scaling algorithm above does work.